# Any good reason why Tuple.Equals does not check exact types?

Tags: c#

Failure to check for type can lead to [un-symmetric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx) equality:

```
public sealed class MyClass : Tuple<string>
{
    private readonly int _b;

    public MyClass(string a, int b) : base(a)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as MyClass);
    }

    private bool Equals(MyClass obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        return base.Equals(obj) && obj._b == _b;
    }
}

[Test]
public void Show_broken_symmetric_equality()
{
    Tuple<string> a = Tuple.Create("Test");
    var b = new MyClass("Test", 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(b, a);
}
```

That test passes, but it should not, it shows the symmetric property of a well implemented `Equals` is broken.

Looking at the code for [`Tuple`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs) that's because Tuple doesn't check the **concrete** types match, i.e. there is no equivalent of `GetType() == obj.GetType()`. It checks assignability, with an `is` check, but doesn't compare types.

There's nothing I can do in `MyClass` to fix this situation, because the incorrect line is `Assert.AreEqual(a, b);` which is the call to `Tuple.Equals`. And, as juharr points out, changing `MyClass.Equals` to return true in this case would break transitivity.

Long shot, but I wonder if anyone knows a good reason why it has been implemented in such a way? Or why it was not sealed if it was implemented this way.

Comment: It is not the only weird thing about Tuple. The implementation is terrible, it is slow and clumsy. My suggestion is not to use Tuple at all...

Comment: I suppose the equality-check DOES check for the type the same way you check on `MyClass` However you can cast an instance of `MyClass` to `Tuple<string>` and then compare the members. Thus this check is perfectly valid.

Comment: But [`Tuple<T>.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346(v=vs.110).aspx) checks the types. _"The obj parameter is considered to be equal to the current instance under the following conditions:
**It is a Tuple<T1, T2> object.**
Its two components are of the same types as the current instance.
Its two components are equal to those of the current instance. Equality is determined by the default object equality comparer for each component."_

Comment: Technically your `Equals` could check if the type is `Tuple<sting>` first then return the `base.Equals` in that case and it would be symmetric.  If you don't want your class to every be equal to a `Tuple<string>` then the simple answer is to not inherit from it in the first place.

Comment: This is the cause: `Tuple<T1> objTuple = other as Tuple<T1>;` (reference source link - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,100). Well, my question would be "if `Equals` is implemented like this, then why `Tuple<...>` classes are not sealed?".

Comment: Sorry @TimSchmelter I don't follow. Check MSDN advice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx There is no `this.GetType() != p.GetType()` in `Tuple` equals. You need to check actual types, not assignability. (NB, I sealed in example, so I don't need to)

Comment: @weston: sure there is: `Tuple<T1, T2> objTuple = other as Tuple<T1, T2>;if (objTuple == null) return false; ....`. [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,f86621ced34a4ba4) So it checks first ith both types are equal with the `as`-operator.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But you appreciate that an `is` relationship is not the same as `a.GetType() != b.GetType()` right? I know you must do, but I feel like you are ignoring what I am saying and the MSDN advice I linked to.

Comment: @juharr If you think I could fix the situation in my class. I would like to see that in an answer.

Comment: @weston - I've looked at that page you're linking to. There is a type comparison in the *example*, but none of the steps at the top of that page say that strict type equality *must* be part of any individual implementer's equality definition.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but you must enforce symmetry in some way (condition 2). Two ways I know of are sealing and use `as/is`, or compare concrete types and `Tuple` does neither.

Comment: @weston It would give you symmetry, but it would not give you the transitive property, so I would not consider it valid.

Answer (score 2):

No, I have looked at this before and as far as I understand there is no good reason why they don't check the type properly (except for that they got it wrong from the start and then it's of course impossible to change it).

Every MSDN advice on best practice for equals talks about doing "GetType() != obj.GetType()" to make sure the types are *exactly* the same, but equals in Tuple only does a cast with 'as' operator which will (as you noticed) give unexpected result and disable the ability for derived classes to adhere to best practices for equals.

IMHO - Don't derive from Tuple, and definitely don't implement equals if you do it.

Comment: Certainly I've come to the same conclusion, with the extra bit of advice that you cannot change behaviour of `GetHashCode` either.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented an alternative that does check type and as far as I'm concerned correctly implements equality contract:

https://mercurynuget.github.io/SuperTuples/

To create a class with `GetHashcode` and `Equals` implementation (plus a `ToString` also like Tuple), optionally caches the hash.

```
public class Person : Suple<string, string>
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        : base(firstName, lastName, SupleHash.Cached)
    {
    }

    public string FirstName => Item1;
    public string LastName => Item2;
}
```

It's implementation is simpler than `Tuple` so may do more boxing during `Equals`, but practically it out performs `Tuple`'s `Equals` and by as much as by 8 times when the hash is cached (`SupleHash.Cached`) and hash caching minimizes boxing and other `Equals` calls, as the `Equals` compares the cached hash first.

Available on nuget:

> Install-Package SuperTuples

As an example of how it works, this is the code for the tripple suple:

```
public abstract class Suple<T1, T2, T3>
{
    private readonly T1 _item1;
    private readonly T2 _item2;
    private readonly T3 _item3;
    private readonly int? _cachedHash;

    protected Suple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        _item1 = item1;
        _item2 = item2;
        _item3 = item3;
    }

    protected Suple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, SupleHash hashMode)
    {
        _item1 = item1;
        _item2 = item2;
        _item3 = item3;
        _cachedHash = CalculateHashCode();
    }

    protected T1 Item1 { get { return _item1; } }
    protected T2 Item2 { get { return _item2; } }
    protected T3 Item3 { get { return _item3; } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        // here's the missing Tuple type comparison
        if (GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

        var other = (Suple<T1, T2, T3>) obj;

        // attempt to avoid equals comparison by using the
        // cached hash if provided by both objects
        if (_cachedHash != null &&
            other._cachedHash != null &&
            _cachedHash != other._cachedHash) return false;

        return Equals(_item1, other._item1) &&
               Equals(_item2, other._item2) &&
               Equals(_item3, other._item3);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _cachedHash ?? CalculateHashCode();
    }

    private int CalculateHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashcode = 0;
            hashcode += _item1 != null ? _item1.GetHashCode() : 0;
            hashcode *= 31;
            hashcode += _item2 != null ? _item2.GetHashCode() : 0;
            hashcode *= 31;
            hashcode += _item3 != null ? _item3.GetHashCode() : 0;
            return hashcode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to quiz you re "minimizes boxing" part, then I had a look at the source for `Tuple<T1, T2>` and, indeed, it uses `EqualityComparer<Object>.Default` to compare items, leading to value type boxing.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I was saying how my implementation with hash cache enabled, minimises the boxing compared to my implementation hash cache off. I always thought the Tuple code is actually so complex to avoid boxing, e.g.: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,542680fa5b2d828d But you're right, that's just a `EqualityComparer<Object>.Default` So I don't know what they are going for.

Answer (score -4):

See source of Tuple class (line 100)
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,2e0df2b1d6d668a0

The order of evaluation for operators is left to right